# Inserciones en lote en jpa sin hibernate

Tags: jpa

Buenas tardes a todos , estoy con un proyecto para la facultad que trata sobre prestamos de dinero . Estoy trabajando con la API JPA. (SIN HIBERNATE)

Tengo un problema con los tiempos de respuesta de la aplicación conforme crece el numero de entidades a persistir , cuanto mayor es el numero de entidades más demora en persisitir.

El inconveniente se da al momento de registrar un préstamo con una cantidad elevada de cuotas por ej : 96 cuotas , demora mas de 30 segundos en impactar en la base de datos.

Este es el método que otorga un préstamo. El mismo esta definido en el managedBean PrestamoController de tipo Request.

```
 public void otorgarPrestamo() {
    try {
        //Establecemos el estado de cuota como impaga;
        Estadocuota ec = new Estadocuota(2);
        //Aqui si lo tiene al cliente
        prestamo.setIdpersona(cliente);

        prestamo.setIdestadoprestamo(estadoPrestamo);
        // Aqui empezamos a setear los valores del prestamo
        // para eso le pasamos los valores del bean frances
        prestamo.setMontoprestado(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getMontoSolicitado()));
        prestamo.setFechaSolicitud(frances.getFechaSolicitud());
        prestamo.setCantidadCuotas(frances.getPlazo());
        prestamo.setTna(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getTasa()));
        prestamo.setGastosAdm(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getGo()));
        prestamo.setSeguroVida(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getSv()));
        prestamo.setIva(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getIv()));
        // Persisito el prestamo
        prestamoFacade.create(prestamo);
        // Deberia crear las cuotas de ese prestamo iterando sobre la lista
        // frances

        List<Frances> coll = frances.getListaFrances();
        //  itero sobre la coleccion de frances
        for (Frances f : coll) { // Esto lo hace muy lento con muchas cuotas
            //  Defino un objeto de tipo cuota
            Cuota c = new Cuota();
            c.setNroCuota(f.getPlazo());
            c.setValorCuota(BigDecimal.valueOf(f.getCuotaTotal()));
            c.setFechaVenc(f.getFechaSolicitud());
            c.setIdestadocuota(ec);
            c.setIdprestamo(prestamo);
            cuotaFacade.create(c);
        }

        JSFUtil.addSuccessMessage(rf.getMensajeArb("info.save"));
        prestamo = new Prestamo();
        estadoPrestamo = new Estadoprestamo();
        //Estadocuota c = new Estadocuota();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JSFUtil.addErrorMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

//CuotaFacade

```
@Stateless
```

public class CuotaFacade extends AbstractFacade {

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.fcastillo_FacilidadesSA_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public CuotaFacade() {
    super(Cuota.class);
}

// retorna lista de cuotas
public List<Cuota> getCuotaList() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Cuota.findAll").getResultList();
}

// Obtener todas las cuotas de un determinado credito
public List<Cuota> buscarPrestamo(int codigoPrestamo) {
    List<Cuota> lista = null;
    String consulta;
    try {
        consulta = "FROM Cuota c WHERE c.idprestamo.idprestamo=?1";
        Query query = em.createQuery(consulta);
        query.setParameter(1, codigoPrestamo);

        lista = query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return lista;
}
```

}

//AbstractFacade

```
import java.util.List;
```

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

/**
 *
 * @author fcastillo
 */
public abstract class AbstractFacade {

```
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
```

}

Yo se que iterar sobre la lista e ir persistiendo las entidades esta mal, pero es una solución rápida que se me ocurrió.

Por favor ¿ alguien podría ayudarme a realizar esas inserciones con el procesamiento en lote ?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos

Edicion 1 -

```
public void otorgarPrestamo() {
```

UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        try {

```
        tx.begin();
        Estadocuota ec = new Estadocuota(2);
        prestamo.setIdpersona(cliente);
        prestamo.setIdestadoprestamo(estadoPrestamo);
        prestamo.setMontoprestado(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getMontoSolicitado()));
        prestamo.setFechaSolicitud(frances.getFechaSolicitud());
        prestamo.setCantidadCuotas(frances.getPlazo());
        prestamo.setTna(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getTasa()));
        prestamo.setGastosAdm(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getGo()));
        prestamo.setSeguroVida(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getSv()));
        prestamo.setIva(BigDecimal.valueOf(frances.getIv()));
        prestamoFacade.create(prestamo);
        List<Frances> coll = frances.getListaFrances();

        for (Frances f : coll) {

            Cuota c = new Cuota();
            c.setNroCuota(f.getPlazo());
            c.setValorCuota(BigDecimal.valueOf(f.getCuotaTotal()));
            c.setFechaVenc(f.getFechaSolicitud());
            c.setIdestadocuota(ec);
            c.setIdprestamo(prestamo);
            cuotaFacade.create(c);

        }
        tx.commit();

        JSFUtil.addSuccessMessage(rf.getMensajeArb("info.save"));
        prestamo = new Prestamo();
        estadoPrestamo = new Estadoprestamo();
        //Estadocuota c = new Estadocuota();

    } catch (Exception e) {
       if(tx!=null){
tx.rollback();
        }
        JSFUtil.addErrorMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: A ver, JPA sólo define el API, por debajo tiene que haber una implementación. Así que no se trata de decir "sin Hibernate" sino qué implementación usas (¿EclipseLink?)

Comment: En todo caso, sin ver el codigo del `cuotaFacade` no se puede decir nada... suena a que estés abriendo una transacción/conexión distinta para cada cuota, en vez de usar una sola para guardarlas todas.

Comment: @SJuan76 Claro , me refería a que uso EclipseLink aquí dejo el cuotaFacade y el abstractFacade

Comment: ¿No utilizas cascade entre las entidades Prestamo y Cuota?